# What is p in (0, 0) is (int x, int y) p for?

Tags: c#

#### Case A

Here `x` and `y` become scalar variables of values `0` each.

```
if ((0, 0) is (int x, int y))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x + y}");
}

if ((object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x + y}");
}
```

#### Case B

The following is compilable but I don't understand what `p` is for.
`x`, `y` are scalar variables and `p` is a tuple with fields `Item1` and `Item2` (rather than `x` and `y`).

```
if ((0, 0) is (int x, int y) p)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x + y} and {p.Item1 + p.Item2}");
}
```

And the following does not compile due to the existence of `p`.

```
if ((object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y) p)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x + y} and {p.Item1 + p.Item2}");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Pattern matching in a value tuple

Comment: what complie error is thrown. can you please share.

Comment: You understand `object o = "foo"; bool b = o is string s`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes. I knew this declaration pattern. It is similar to `string s; if(o is string){s=(string)o;}`.

Comment: @TheRealMasochist: well, isn't it the same then? You declare a variable `s` which is initialized/assigned if the type pattern matches. If it doesn't match you can't use it. The [`ValueTuple<int,int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2?view=net-6.0) is also just a type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: In the case 3, why is `bool s = (object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y) p;` illegal?

Comment: @TheRealMasochist: i don't know the compiler error. But you cast it to `System.Object` first and that cannot be deconstructed to that ValueTuple<int,int> i

Comment: @TimSchmelter: What is the diff between `bool s = (object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y) ;` (ok) and `bool s = (object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y) p;` (error)?

Comment: `bool s = (object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y);` is just a type check. `bool s = (object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y) p;` is a form of pattern matching that is trying to assign `(object)(0,0)` to the variable `p` that is of type `(int x, int y)`, which involves trying to deconstruct the value. Again, the first is _only_ a type check, nothing more. In the same way you could also do `string str = "foo"; bool s = (object)str is List<int>;` It's a pointless but still a legal type check. I guess the compiler doesn't possess the logic to detect deconstruction failing as part of the `is` pattern matching.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace: `bool s = (object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y);` is not just a type check but also it assigns `0` to both `x` and `y` as independent variables rather than tuple fields.

Comment: No, it doesn't assign x and y: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xxqyk3. It declares the local variables x and y, but it doesn't assign anything...

Comment: I mean, it's still kind of weird that `bool s = (object)(0, 0) is (int x, int y);` is declaring the local variables x and y for something that is just a type check. I don't know, though, if this was an intentional design decision by the language team, or just an incidental side-effect of how tuple declarations are processed by the compiler that was deemed too costly to special-case in the compiler.

Comment: `bool s = (object)(0, 0) is (int, int);` is just a type check (note that there's no `x` or `y` being assigned). With `x` and `y`, it's a type check *and* a deconstruction. Not weird at all.

Comment: @madreflection: and then, what is `p` in `bool s = (0,0) is (int x, int y) p` for?

Comment: The confusing bit comes in when you think that `(int x, int y) p` declares a tuple with named members, which it doesn't in this expression. To get that, you'd have to write `(x: 0, y: 0) is (int, int) p`. The `(object)` case is a bit unfortunate in that it's a deconstruct when you want a type check -- you have to write `(object) (0, 0) is ValueTuple<int, int> p` (and there's no opportunity to name the members with any syntax). This makes *some* sense in that named tuples are compile-time only types, and no names are available in `object`, which would making a type check with names ambiguous.

Comment: I fact, there is a dedicated error for expressions like `(object) (0, 0) is (x: int, y: int)`, showing that pattern matching with names on `object` is explicitly prohibited because no type information is available in this case, while checks like `(0, 0) is (x: int, y: int)` fail (since the names don't match). The merits of making this case work consistently vs. the value of being able to deconstruct into a tuple with named members is debatable, but at least there's sense in it.

Comment: Most of this comes from the desire to make the old `Tuple` class work the same as `ValueTuple`, through the `ITuple` interface. `(object) (0, 0)` and `(object) new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0)` allow the same syntax for checking and deconstructing (for better or worse), but of course they're still not the same type, and going through `object` really gets you into weird territory here. `o is (int, int)` is very different from `o is ValueTuple<int, int>`. The shortest syntax to unambiguously check for and assign a `ValueTuple` should be `if (o is ValueTuple<int, int> p) { (int x, int y) q = p; ... }`.